# Can I pass in parameters to paho callback functions in python?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

So I'm making a python program to track mqtt connections on topics so that I can have a dashboard of connections. I have a variable that I want to pass into the `on_message` function so that I can modify it, and print it out.

I already know I can make the variable `global` by just declaring it to be so, but from my experience declaring things to be `global` is to be avoided at all costs, so I'm wondering if there's another way.

(code is abridged for readability's sake)

```py
def process_message(client, userdata, message):
    global connected_list

    # mess around with it and exit the callback


if __name__ == "__main__":
    connected_list = []

    # set up the mosquitto client and then

    client.on_message = process_message

    # tell it to subscribe and connect and then

    client.loop_forever()
```

Basically I know that it can be done with `global` but I'd quite like to avoid it if possible. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help guys, I did a mix of both suggestions and now have a class that contains both the list and also the lock, so I can easily lock and unlock the list when I'm operating on it.

Comment: Just be careful and avoid race conditions if your code access/modify the global variable from multiple threads (list object methods cannot be guaranteed to be atomic)

Comment: Great point Victor! Will definitely check this out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try putting all the callbacks as methods in a class. The state could then be variables initialized in `__init__` instead of global variables. This greatly improves the reusability of your code.

```
class Handler:

    def __init__(self):
        self.connected_list = []

    def process_message(self, client, userdata, message):
        connected_list = self.connected_list

        # mess around with it and exit the callback


if __name__ == "__main__":
    handler = Handler()

    client.on_message = handler.process_message

    # tell it to subscribe and connect and then

    client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: That's a great idea! Thanks so much :)